# What is the purpose of this 'a' in this array slicing in Python ( W[: , : , : , a] )?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-slicing

Here is the code example:

```
weights = W[:,:,:,a]
```

**Here, a is an integer number**

In array slicing, I need a good explanation (references are a plus) on Python's slice notation. I don't understand what is the purpose of this 'a'. We know that a 3D array is like a stack of matrices where:

- The first index, i, selects the matrix
- The second index, j, selects the row
- The third index, k, selects the column

Comment: It looks like a 4D numpy array, not 3D.

Comment: @NafizAhmed yes, it is a 4D array here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Shapes:

Let **M** to be the your **n**-dimensional array:

> Reference image: https://fgnt.github.io/python_crashkurs_doc/_images/numpy_array_t.png

1. A shape of **M** (x,) means your array have **x lines**
2. A shape of **M** (x, y) means your array have **x lines** and **y columns**
3. A shape of **M** (x, y, z) means your array have **x lines**, **y columns** and **z "layers"**

If you want you can think of shapes as (*lines*, *columns*, *layers*,...), but things become complicated when you talk about four-dimensional arrays or greater (maybe you could name them as *stacks of blocks* for the fourth dimension).

Anyway, a way better naming convention is the following:

**M** (*axis 0*, *axis 1*, *axis 2*, ..., *axis n*) as shown in the reference image.

To find the shape of array in Python, simply write: `M.shape`

## **Slicing:**

In array indexing, the comma separates the dimensions of an array:
**M** [*axis 0*, *axis 1*, *axis 2*, ..., *axis n*]
For each axis you can have the following slice structure:

**[ start : stop : step ]** where:

1. **start**: the first index for the selected axis (included in the result)

- **start = 0** is the default start index (does not need to be specified)

2. **stop**: the last index for the selected axis (not included in the result)

- **stop = len(axis)** is the default end index (does not need to be specified)

3. **step**: the step of traversing the selected axis:

- **step = 0** is not allowed
- **step = 1** is the default step (does not need to be specified)
- **step = -1** means reverse traversing
- **step = n** means from **n** to **n** step

The following slicings are equivalent:
**M** [0:n+1:1], **M** [:] and **M**[::] according to **default** values.

Mixed together, now we can write in a generic slicing notation:

**M** [*start-index-for-axis **0** : stop-index-for-axis **0** : step-for-axis **0***,
     *start-index-for-axis **1** : stop-index-for-axis **1** : step-for-axis **1***,
     *start-index-for-axis **2** : stop-index-for-axis **2** : step-for-axis **2***,
     ...
     *start-index-for-axis **n** : stop-index-for-axis **n** : step-for-axis **n**]*,

Enough theory, let's see some **examples**:

We have **M**, a two-dimensional array, with a (5, 5) shape:

```
M = np.arange(1, 26).reshape(5, 5)
print(M)
```

result:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
[ 6  7  8  9 10]
[11 12 13 14 15]
[16 17 18 19 20]
[21 22 23 24 25]]
```

```
print('Traverse the matrix from the last line to the first one (axis=0)', matrix[::-1],  sep='\n')
```

Result:

```
[[21 22 23 24 25]
[16 17 18 19 20]
[11 12 13 14 15]
[ 6  7  8  9 10]
[ 1  2  3  4  5]]
```

```
print('The 3 columns in the middle of the matrix (take all data from axis=0, and take a slice from axis=1):' , matrix[:, 1:4],sep='\n')
```

Result:

```
[[ 2  3  4]
[ 7  8  9]
[12 13 14]
[17 18 19]
[22 23 24]]
```

Now, your slice: **W** [:, :, :, *a*], where  *a* is an integer variable, can be interpreted as:

- **M** is a four-dimensional array
- you take all from *axis 0*, *axis 1* and *axis 2*
- you take just the index *a* from *axis 3*

A four-dimensional array can be imagined as a stack/array of three-dimensional blocks, and your slice means: take the *a* column from each matrix from each block, and ends up with a three-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks.I understand.